# core data: how to save programmatically created object data model

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-data

In my app i create the data model dynamically during the first launch. Is there a way to save this data model so i can access this model in subsequent app launches (for example as a *.momd-file)?

Comment: I'm curious: why do you need to create the data model at launch time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It [doesn't look](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectModel_Class/Reference/Reference.html) like there is a method that saves your model to a .momd file, but NSManagedObjectModel *does* implement `<NSCoding>`, so you can use NSArchiver / NSUnarchiver to write the model out to a file and read it back in later.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to load default data set from a different persistent store.

Just load 1st graph from a bundle persistent store, copy objects to document persistent store and save it.

You might find more inspiration here: http://www.raywenderlich.com/980/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data

Comment: That would be good for the actual _data_, but I understood the question to be about saving and loading the _model_ (i.e. what entities,attributes and relationships are present). I could be wrong, though...